# Why are the "Dragon Ruler" series of cards banned in official tournaments?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

"Dragon Ruler" is a *Yu-Gi-Oh!* card series which consists of eight cards:

***Redox, Dragon Ruler of Boulders***

> If this card is in your hand or Graveyard: You can banish a total of 2 EARTH and/or Dragon-Type monsters from your hand and/or Graveyard, except this card; Special Summon this card. During your opponent's End Phase, if this card was Special Summoned: Return it to the hand. You can discard this card and 1 EARTH monster to the Graveyard, then target 1 monster in your Graveyard; Special Summon that target. If this card is banished: You can add 1 EARTH Dragon-Type monster from your Deck to your hand. You can only use 1 "Redox, Dragon Ruler of Boulders" effect per turn, and only once that turn.

***Tempest, Dragon Ruler of Storms***

> If this card is in your hand or Graveyard: You can banish a total of 2 WIND and/or Dragon-Type monsters from your hand and/or Graveyard, except this card; Special Summon this card. During your opponent's End Phase, if this card was Special Summoned: Return it to the hand. You can discard this card and 1 WIND monster to the Graveyard; add 1 Dragon-Type monster from your Deck to your hand. If this card is banished: You can add 1 WIND Dragon-Type monster from your Deck to your hand. You can only use 1 "Tempest, Dragon Ruler of Storms" effect per turn, and only once that turn.

***Blaster, Dragon Ruler of Infernos***

> If this card is in your hand or Graveyard: You can banish a total of 2 FIRE and/or Dragon-Type monsters from your hand and/or Graveyard, except this card; Special Summon this card. During your opponent's End Phase, if this card was Special Summoned: Return it to the hand. You can discard this card and 1 FIRE monster to the Graveyard, then target 1 card on the field; destroy that target. If this card is banished: You can add 1 FIRE Dragon-Type monster from your Deck to your hand. You can only use 1 "Blaster, Dragon Ruler of Infernos" effect per turn, and only once that turn

***Tidal, Dragon Ruler of Waterfalls***

> If this card is in your hand or Graveyard: You can banish a total of 2 WATER and/or Dragon-Type monsters from your hand and/or Graveyard, except this card; Special Summon this card. During your opponent's End Phase, if this card was Special Summoned: Return it to the hand. You can discard this card and 1 WATER monster to the Graveyard; send 1 monster from your Deck to the Graveyard. If this card is banished: You can add 1 WATER Dragon-Type monster from your Deck to your hand. You can only use 1 "Tidal, Dragon Ruler of Waterfalls" effect per turn, and only once that turn.

***Reactan, Dragon Ruler of Pebbles***

> You can discard this card AND 1 Dragon-Type or EARTH monster; Special Summon 1 "Redox, Dragon Ruler of Boulders" from your Deck. It cannot attack this turn. You can only use the effect of "Reactan, Dragon Ruler of Pebbles" once per turn.

***Lightning, Dragon Ruler of Drafts***

> You can discard this card AND 1 Dragon-Type or WIND monster; Special Summon 1 "Tempest, Dragon Ruler of Storms" from your Deck. It cannot attack this turn. You can only use the effect of "Lightning, Dragon Ruler of Drafts" once per turn.

***Burner, Dragon Ruler of Sparks***

> You can discard this card AND 1 Dragon-Type or FIRE monster; Special Summon 1 "Blaster, Dragon Ruler of Infernos" from your Deck. It cannot attack this turn. You can only use the effect of "Burner, Dragon Ruler of Sparks" once per turn.

***Stream, Dragon Ruler of Droplets***

> You can discard this card AND 1 Dragon-Type or WATER monster; Special Summon 1 "Tidal, Dragon Ruler of Waterfalls" from your Deck. It cannot attack this turn. You can only use the effect of "Stream, Dragon Ruler of Droplets" once per turn

My question is: **Why are the adult Dragon Rulers (Redox, Tempest, Blaster and Tidal) Forbidden?**

My argument:

- (From personal experience) : I have all of them, and have never experienced any difficulties, a very powerful move, even when we used all of the effects.

As by this  [*Yu-Gi-Oh!* Wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:What_is_wrong_with_Dragon_Rulers%3F),

> They never die if there's enough resources, and when all of their keys cards were unaffected, there were ALWAYS more resources as they'd search themselves out when banished as the costs to summon another. They make Rank 7 monsters, which are some of the most powerful in the game, with ease, can be sent to the graveyard with ease, and can search from almost anywhere. There's usually a play you can do with them. If I remember righty, the key build right now is the Hieratic Rulers. Don't quote me on all this though, seeing as I just took a glance at your statement and decided to answer in some manner.

I don't agree with this. At all.

First of all, although they never die, the cost is heavy if used repeatedly. The most they can do is 10 summons in a normal sized deck, and this has to be done over 10 turns. And if they used the "Babys" They can't even attack! Even if they did use their own effect to revive, they'd have to be recalled, drastically draining the deck!

Also, they would require many cards to get banished! This would mean a massive pile of banished cards, with only a few cards to get them out, which only a selected few can do! Additionally, there is not more resources, as eventuaally, as I have said *all cards will get eventually banished before any real damage is caused!*

Have I missed anything? I am pretty disappointed, because this is the deck I would have used for TCG Tournaments, and they pretty much are the only good cards I have!

Comment: This looks pretty close to a "Banning these cards is stupid, am I right?" question, which is just a rant in disguise of a question (and those are off-topic). I think that "Why were these banned" is perfectly on-topic, but it might be helpful to remove some of the personal sidenotes, like how you are upset that they were banned because they were the only goods cards you have.

Comment: @Thunderforge , I literally only gave 1 statement about myself! That's a bit harsh isn't it? And what does rant mean?

Comment: I think you missed the part where, once [Dark Matter Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_95:_Galaxy-Eyes_Dark_Matter_Dragon) came out, DRulers were one of the most powerful series around again, even with their supporters banned and they themselves limited.  4 cards out of 40-60, with only generic dragon support, and yet they still ended up dominating events.

Comment: It's kinda like if harpies were limited to 1 Channeler, 1 Dancer, 1 Lady, and 1 Hunting Ground, with all of their other cards banned, but they could still consistently beat Zoodiacs & True Dracos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a pretty good [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/3n147q/what_was_dragon_rulers_and_why_was_it_so_op/) on the subject. It sounds like they were dominating events, and several attempts to limit them without banning were unsuccessful.

> TL;DR: Very strong monsters. Come from anywhere. Don't die. Can combine into stronger ones. So strong it took Konami (3-4?) lists to finally kill them.

Comment: I would accept this, but I don't use Reddit :-(. It is slow, and I have no more memory on my phone. I have to keep clearing out RAM, memory and all that!

Comment: Could you post a copy of the thread? I am anoying aren't I?!

Comment: You don't have to have a reddit account to read the content. It is way too long to post it all here, which is why I just posted the summary.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Yeah, after a gruelling attempt, I read it all lol

Comment: @VortexYT I suggest you watch on youtube or similar the Championship Final of that year (it was in [2013](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/World_Championship_2013)) so you get an idea on how broken Dragon Rulers where.. they searched themselves, destroyed things, summoned multiple copies etc... they were REALLY fast and powerful, as they also could benefit from the "best" XYZ and synchro cards that were in that date.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I watched it ages ago, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Theres some very important cards that you are overlooking that made them deadly. Super Rejuvenation, gold sarcophagus, dragon shrine, burial from a different dimension, card destruction, and red eyes dark metal as a unit kept this deck running like a well oiled machine. Also any monster that couldn't attack due to babys were getting xyz'd out anyways. Even with master rule 4 in place, the existence of dragin link deck makes the return of dragon ruler one that I would be a bit terrified of.

Answer (score -5):

I think dragon rulers should come back in this time because with the extra monster zone on the field it can't be that OP anymore because the cost of a dragon ruler is once a turn and with soul charge ban sure you can use them for a link summon but you can't do anything with them so I think all of them should be unbanned and be at least at 2 each